# How to get my results grouped by the SO Number in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I hope you can help me. It is something simple but I just can't get it done.

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT Orders.Rec AS [SO Number], Parts.ShortID AS [Item ID], Parts.Description AS [Item Description], Sum(([MatOut].[UnitPrice]+[MatOut].[UnitShipCost])*[MatOut].[Qty])/Sum([MatOut].[Qty]) AS [Unit Cost], [OrdersLines].[UnitPrice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion] AS [Unit Price], Sum(MatOut.Qty) AS Units, Sum([MatOut].[Qty]*([OrdersLines].[unitprice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion]-([MatOut].[UnitPrice]+[MatOut].[UnitShipCost]))) AS [P/L Amount], Sum([OrdersLines].[unitprice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion]-([MatOut].[UnitPrice]+[MatOut].[UnitShipCost]))/Sum([MatOut].[UnitPrice]+[MatOut].[UnitShipCost]+0.001) AS [P/L Percent], Orders.PO AS [Customer PO], Orders.AccNumber AS Account, Customer_1.Name AS [Bill To Name], Orders.Created AS [Order Date], Orders.Delivery AS [Req Date], Orders.Shipped AS Shipped, tblCompanyInfo.strLocationName AS Warehouse
FROM Customer AS Customer_1 INNER JOIN ((Orders INNER JOIN tblCompanyInfo ON Orders.WID = tblCompanyInfo.Rec) INNER JOIN ((OrdersLines INNER JOIN Parts ON OrdersLines.Part = Parts.ShortID) INNER JOIN MatOut ON (OrdersLines.RecID = MatOut.OrderID) AND (Parts.PartNo = MatOut.PartNo) AND (OrdersLines.Rec = MatOut.Ref)) ON (Orders.Rec = OrdersLines.Rec) AND (Orders.Rec = OrdersLines.Rec)) ON Customer_1.Rec = Orders.Associate
WHERE (((Orders.Complete)<>0) AND ((Orders.Canceled)=0) AND ((MatOut.OutStatus)=-4))
GROUP BY Orders.Rec, Parts.ShortID, Parts.Description, Orders.PO, Orders.AccNumber, Customer_1.Name, Orders.Created, Orders.Delivery, Orders.Shipped, tblCompanyInfo.strLocationName, OrdersLines.UnitPrice/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion], [OrdersLines].[Qty]*([OrdersLines].[unitprice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion]-[parts].[curcost]), ([OrdersLines].[unitprice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion]-[parts].[curcost])/([parts].[curcost]+0.001);
```

It is showing the results as shown in the image, for each `Item ID`. But I need the results just for each `SO Number`.

[image]

I would really thank you if you can let me know how to get the results as I need.

Comment: Don't include ItemID nor ItemDescription in query. Should provide raw data and desired output at text tables, not images.

Comment: I've tried it but it's not working. The query is getting the price and cost for each line item. I think I would need to make a sum to get the total for each SO number.

Comment: Yes, you have several tables in that query, possibly need to greatly simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question editing queue is full, I've re-posted the SQL below in an outline format for readability. I agree with @June7 about simplifying this query, possibly breaking it up into sub-queries. Without *knowing* your data, it's difficult to analyze this from afar. The two things that jump out at me are, consider using the [HAVING clause](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/having-clause-64c52dba-5cda-45c5-98b5-bd155a89f02f) instead of WHERE, and GROUP BY has a 10 field limit. You are GROUPING on 10 table fields and 3 calculated fields. I don't know if the calculated fields are counted in that limit. If the Query Builder did not raise a !Run error, then probably not.

If HAVING doesn't work, I would start troubleshooting by hand sketching a schema like model containing some data, and including some entity relationship symbols. Then I would copy the Query Builder SQL into the VBA editor, so I can comment out the calculated fields, and the joins (inner most first). I would also try to incorporate the WHERE clauses (aka Cartesian Joins) into INNER JOINS. You can use *QueryDefs* and *OpenQuery* to view the results in a Datasheet.

**QueryDefs Example**

```
strSQL = "SELECT Orders.Rec AS [SO Number], [...];"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourQueryName").SQL = strSQL
DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourQueryName", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
```

**Your SQL Formatted**

```
SELECT Orders.Rec AS [SO Number], 
    Parts.ShortID AS [Item ID], 
    Parts.Description AS [Item Description], 
    Sum(([MatOut].[UnitPrice]+[MatOut].[UnitShipCost])*[MatOut].[Qty])/ Sum([MatOut].[Qty]) AS [Unit Cost], 
    [OrdersLines].[UnitPrice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion] AS [Unit Price], 
    Sum(MatOut.Qty) AS Units, 
    Sum([MatOut].[Qty]*([OrdersLines].[unitprice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion]-([MatOut].[UnitPrice]+[MatOut].[UnitShipCost]))) AS [P/L Amount], 
    Sum([OrdersLines].[unitprice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion]-([MatOut].[UnitPrice]+[MatOut].[UnitShipCost]))/Sum([MatOut].[UnitPrice]+[MatOut].[UnitShipCost]+0.001) AS [P/L Percent], 
    Orders.PO AS [Customer PO], 
    Orders.AccNumber AS Account, 
    Customer_1.Name AS [Bill To Name], 
    Orders.Created AS [Order Date], 
    Orders.Delivery AS [Req Date], 
    Orders.Shipped AS Shipped, 
    tblCompanyInfo.strLocationName AS Warehouse
FROM Customer AS Customer_1 
    INNER JOIN ((Orders 
        INNER JOIN tblCompanyInfo ON Orders.WID = tblCompanyInfo.Rec) 
        INNER JOIN ((OrdersLines 
          INNER JOIN Parts ON OrdersLines.Part = Parts.ShortID) 
            INNER JOIN MatOut ON (OrdersLines.RecID = MatOut.OrderID) 
              AND (Parts.PartNo = MatOut.PartNo) AND (OrdersLines.Rec = MatOut.Ref)) 
                ON (Orders.Rec = OrdersLines.Rec) AND (Orders.Rec = OrdersLines.Rec)) 
                  ON Customer_1.Rec = Orders.Associate
WHERE (((Orders.Complete)<>0) 
    AND ((Orders.Canceled)=0) 
    AND ((MatOut.OutStatus)=-4))
GROUP BY Orders.Rec, 
    Parts.ShortID, 
    Parts.Description, 
    Orders.PO, 
    Orders.AccNumber, 
    Customer_1.Name, 
    Orders.Created, 
    Orders.Delivery, 
    Orders.Shipped, 
    tblCompanyInfo.strLocationName, 
    OrdersLines.UnitPrice/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion], 
    [OrdersLines].[Qty]*([OrdersLines].[unitprice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion]-[parts].[curcost]), 
    ([OrdersLines].[unitprice]/[Orders].[CurrencyConversion]-[parts].[curcost])/([parts].[curcost]+0.001);
```